# Table cell image is not displaying

Tags: html, css

Table cell image and cell background image is not displaying:

```html
<table border="1">
 <colgroup>
   <col width="150"/>
   <col width="350"/>
 </colgroup>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td height="100%" width="92%"><image src="../images/refresh.jpg" alt="Test"></td>
    <td background="https://media.giphy.com/media/10S1CGpBU06FZ6/giphy.gif" width="8%"></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Maybe you have written a wrong path

Comment: try this background-image: url("../images/refresh.jng");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try this.

```
<table border="1">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="150"/>
        <col width="350"/>
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td height="100%" width="100%"><img src="../images/refresh.jpg" alt="Test"></td>
            <td style="background:url(../images/refresh.jpg);" width="100%"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Since it is `img` not `image` and `TD` element dosn't have the `background` attribute, you can put your custom style inside the `style` attribute just like above.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```
<td style="background-image: url('../images/refresh.jpg')" width="100%">
```

Also, it's probably pretty likely that your path is incorrect. Try inserting:

```
  <?php if(file_exists("../images/refresh.jpg")){
  echo "IT EXISTS!";
  }
  else{
  echo "NOT FOUND!";
  }
  ?>
```

That should tell you if your path is correct or not.

Answer (score 2):

`<image>` is not a tag, it is abbreviated the to `<img>`, so it should be something like this: `<**img** src="../images/refresh.jpg" alt="Test">`.

In the following example I added an image from the net to show you:

```css
td {
  border: solid 1px black
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <colgroup>
    <col width="150" />
    <col width="350" />
  </colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td height="100%" width="100%"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="Test"></td>
      <td style="background:url(../images/refresh.jpg);" width="100%"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not seeing anything since the first `td` is 100%.

Change the first `td` to take up 92% or anything less than 100% of the width.

```
<td height="100%" width="92%"><image src="../images/refresh.jpg" alt="Test">    </td>
<td background="../images/refresh.jpg" width="8%"></td>
```

```html
<table border="1">
 <colgroup>
   <col width="150"/>
   <col width="350"/>
 </colgroup>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td height="100%" width="92%"><image src="../images/refresh.jpg" alt="Test"></td>
    <td background="https://media.giphy.com/media/10S1CGpBU06FZ6/giphy.gif" width="8%"></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```